# Understanding on git remote

Tags: git, github

I am new to git, and having difficulty in understanding git remote. Suppose a scenario where me and my friend ("Mr X") works on a project ("MapTest"). I have created the project MapTest and added to repo.

Now the command `git remote` gives me the result

**> origin**

My doubt is

1)Now Mr X could directly clone this project in his local, then when should we use
`git remote add [shortname] [url]` command?

2)is it me or Mr X who should run `git remote add` command?

I went through many posts but was not able to find answers to these posts, sorry if its dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Mr X clones your repository, then your repository will be shown as origin in his local repository. If you want to pull or push from his repository, then you should use remote add to be able to use the shortcut (as origin) to not having to specify the URL to pull from or push to every time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, which means I can use git remote add only after he clones my repository. is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes and no.... I think you can use `git remote add` even if the repository you are pointing to doesn't exist yet (and you already know where it'll be created) but usually you wouldn't do it before it has been created by git clone. Of course, git push <remote> or git pull <remote> won't function until the remote repository has been created.